# RequireJS How to overide a backbone method globably

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am trying to override a the backbone fetch method with a snippet like that:

```
Backbone.sync = function() {
    var savedFetch = Backbone.sync;
    console.log('fetch is overriden');
    return function() {
            return savedFetch.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    }();
```

I have a main app view, that loads all childrens views and i was hopping that dropping the snippet above in the initialize method overide backbone fetch method throughout the entire app as backbone should be export globably ( it's loaded with RequireJS's shim). Problem is that it seems to only impact on the "main app view", so that when fetch are triggered in children views the orginal backbone code is called and not my overridden one.

Any suggestion on how this could be elegantly fixed ?

Thanks